# Is it possible to render TS types or values of variables inside markdown files using static site generators like VitePress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, markdown, vitepress

I want to create a documentation using Vitepress ( or similiar ). This app uses a package which contains types and [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) schemas. The root library index.ts could be

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const userSchema = z
  .object({
    username: z.string().min(1),
  })
  .strict();

type User = z.infer<typeof userSchema>;

export { userSchema, type User }
```

Is there a way to either render the schema or the type inside the markdown file?

*Maybe with the help of Vue files ( VitePress )*

I just want to describe the schema or type but don't want to copy paste all the fields from it because then I have to take care that everything is in sync.

Comment: You have the type at runtime in the form of a zod schema.

Comment: yes I do. And VitePress should render the structure of the schema or type ( one is fine )

Comment: Okay this is not as easy as I thougnt, you'll need either a runtime highlighter or compile-time interface generation (via a vitepress plugin like https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/02ccce9ad961ef2c9fd6a3ff182daf6e4157407a/packages/.vitepress/plugins/markdownTransform.ts#L2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod-to-ts to convert your schema to
   a runtime typescript-lang string
2. Use [`ts-vue Code Blocks`](https://vitepress.dev/guide/using-vue#unescape-in-code-blocks) ro render it

````
<script setup lang="ts">
import { printNode, zodToTs } from 'zod-to-ts'
import { UserSchema } from './schemas'

const identifier = 'User'
const { node } = zodToTs(UserSchema, identifier)
const nodeString = printNode(node)
</script>

```ts-vue
// {{ identifier }} Schema
{{ nodeString }}
```
````

Comment: very nice! Do you know if syntax highlighting is possible? because `ts-vue` is required to work but then you loose support for TS syntax highlighting

Comment: @baitendbidz docs: `To enable Vue-style interpolation inside fences, you can append the language with the -vue suffix, e.g. js-vue` so that should be default TS syntax highlighting

Comment: I tried to setup a Stackblitz example, I hope this helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-hrkkdg?file=package.json

Comment: if you get an error, I had to install `typescript` and then it worked for me. Somehow I can't save a new version anymore